# Whonix - whonix-gw keeps saying start condition has not been met

Tags: tor, whonix, qubes

I have started the tor service with no issue on whonix-ws and anon-whonix (although both won't connect to Tor because of this issue I'm having). I can also confirm that I have a connection on sys-net to clearnet just fine.

When I try to start the tor service on whonix-gw I keep getting the following error. I have used `sudo service tor start`, `sudo service tor@default start` and one or two other commands but no luck.

```
user@host:~$ sudo service tor start
user@host:~$ sudo service tor status
● tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/tor.service.d
           └─30_qubes.conf, 40_qubes.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
           start condition failed at Sat 2017-03-18 15:27:04 AEDT; 2s ago
           ConditionPathExists=/var/run/qubes-service/whonix-gateway was not met

Mar 18 15:25:08 host systemd[1]: Started Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
Mar 18 15:27:04 host systemd[1]: Started Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
```

I am out of ideas and hoping someone else has come across this before.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to manually start Tor in whonix-ws or anon-whonix. whonix-ws is the Whonix-Workstation template and anon-whonix is the default Whonix-Workstation AppVM.

Neither you should manually start Tor in whonix-gw. It's not supposed to be started inside the TemplateVM.

Tor gets automatically started in sys-whonix (which should a TemplateBasedProxyVM based on whonix-gw).

Please follow the Qubes-Whonix setup instructions here:

https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Qubes/Install